# Scala groupBy to map from list

Tags: scala

I have List like this and want to convert them into map

```
val myList = List(
    "IDENTIFIER, a, b, c", 
    "IDENTIFIER, d, e,f",
    "INFORMATION, a, b, c",
    "INFORMATION, d, e, f"
)
```

Expected output:

```
Map[String,List[String]] = Map(IDENTIFIER -> List(a b c, d e f), INFORMATION -> List(a b c, d e f))`
```

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. Presumably you have tried to write the code but come across a problem. Tell us the particular problem you found so we can help fix it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

***Given List:***

```
val myList = List(
    "IDENTIFIER, a, b, c", 
    "IDENTIFIER, d, e, f",
    "INFORMATION, a, b, c",
    "INFORMATION, d, e, f"
)
```

***Using,***

```
myList.map(_.split(",")).groupBy(_.head).mapValues(_.map(_.tail.mkString(" ").trim))
```

***In Scala REPL:***

```
scala> myList.map(_.split(",")).groupBy(_.head).mapValues(_.map(_.tail.mkString(" ").trim))
res91: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[String]] = Map(IDENTIFIER -> List(a  b  c, d  e  f), INFORMATION -> List(a
  b  c, d  e  f))

scala>
```